# optaplanner @ValueRangeProfider for a boolean planning variable [optaplanner]

Tags: optaplanner

Hi all opatplanner users,

My ***planning problem*** is: obtaining valid schedule of remote sensing satellite constellation.

@PlanningEntity:

```
ImageStrip (String taskCode,
            int stripIndex,
            String satellite,
            Timestamp timeSlot,
            boolean selected (planning variable))
```

@PlanningVariable:

```
 boolean selected
```

My ***problem data*** primary is like that:

Image_strip:

D        1          Sat2         22-12-2015 11:02:24.051
D        1          Sat1         22-12-2015 11:03:24.069
A        2          Sat1         22-12-2015 11:04:24.122
A        2          Sat3         22-12-2015 11:06:24.172
B        2          Sat3         22-12-2015 11:07:24.197
B        2          Sat2         22-12-2015 11:08:24.284
D        1          Sat3         22-12-2015 11:10:24.042
A        3          Sat1         22-12-2015 11:10:24.395
A        2          Sat2         22-12-2015 11:10:24.441
A        1          Sat2         22-12-2015 11:11:24.456
C        2          Sat1         22-12-2015 11:12:24.465
B        1          Sat1         22-12-2015 11:13:24.469
B        1          Sat2         22-12-2015 11:14:24.551
C        2          Sat2         22-12-2015 11:15:24.556
B        1          Sat3         22-12-2015 11:16:24.642
C        2          Sat3         22-12-2015 11:17:24.648
C        1          Sat3         22-12-2015 11:18:24.738
A        3          Sat3         22-12-2015 11:19:00.469
A        1          Sat1         22-12-2015 11:20:24.123
C        1          Sat2         22-12-2015 11:20:24.827
C        1          Sat1         22-12-2015 11:21:24.916
B        2          Sat1         22-12-2015 11:30:24.373
A        3          Sat2         22-12-2015 11:40:50.750
A        1          Sat3         22-12-2015 11:50:24.789

@PlanningSolution: Schedule

Please, the question is how can I define the value range provider for just a boolean planning variable?
Also I want to use @PlanningVariable(nullable = true) for my planning variable.

i.e. @ValueRangeProvider for the planning variable (boolean selected) defined in the Schedule. And use the over constrained planning condition (nullable = true).

My rule is as follows:

rule "Transition Time Rule"

```
when

    $leftImageStrip:ImageStrip($selected : selected,
                               $satellite : satellite, 
                               selected != null,
                               $timeslot : timeslot)
   $sumTime : Number () from accumulate (
                               $rightImageStrip : ImageStrip(selected == $selected,
                               satellite == $satellite,
                             Math.abs(timeslot.getTime() -                                                 $timeslot.getTime()) <= 180000,
                              this != $leftImageStrip),
                              sum($rightImageStrip.gain))
then
    System.out.println(" SUM = " + $sumTime );
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -$sumTime.intValue());
```

I did the following in the planning entity:

@PlanningVariable(nullable = true, valueRangeProviderRefs = {"selectedRange"})

public Boolean getSelected() { return selected; }

And in the planning solution I put the following:

@ValueRangeProvider(id = "selectedRange")

List getValueRange() { return Arrays.asList(Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE); }

public List getBooleanList() { return selectedList; }

public void setBooleanList(List selectedList) { this.selectedList = selectedList; }

But I received the following error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The entityClass (class org.tasking.domain.ImageStrip) has a PlanningVariable) annotated property (selected) with a valueRangeProviderRef (selectedRange) that does not exist on a registered PlanningSolution or PlanningEntity.

I can't recognize the error cause.
thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Boolean` (not `boolean`), so `null` can represent an uninitialized variable (which makes the entity also uninitialized).

On your Solution:

```
@ValueRangeProvider(...)
List<Boolean> getValueRange() {
     return Arrays.asList(Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have a problem. I did the following:  @PlanningVariable(nullable = true, valueRangeProviderRefs = {"selectedRange"})
 public Boolean getSelected() {
  return selected;
 }
in the planning entity. and in the planning solution I put the following:  @ValueRangeProvider(id = "selectedRange")
 List<Boolean> getValueRange() {
      return Arrays.asList(Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.TRUE);
 }
 public List<Boolean> getBooleanList() {
  return selectedList;
 }

 public void setBooleanList(List<Boolean> selectedList) {
  this.selectedList = selectedList;
 }
but I received the following error

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The entityClass (class org.tasking.domain.ImageStrip) has a PlanningVariable) annotated property (selected) with a valueRangeProviderRef (selectedRange) that does not exist on a registered PlanningSolution or PlanningEntity.